# Update a s3 policy

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to update a s3 bucket policy with new IP addresses. I want to nslookup a domain then apply those IP addresses to the s3 policy under aws:SourceIP. And just a heads up, this is my first rodeo....

```
 import subprocess
import boto3
from awspolicy import BucketPolicy


process = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", "domain"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
output = process.communicate()[0].split('\n')

ip_arr = []
for data in output:
    if 'Address' in data:
        ip_arr.append(data.replace('Address: ',''))
ip_arr.pop(0)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'testwhitelist'

# Load the bucket policy as an object
bucket_policy = BucketPolicy(serviceModule=s3_client, resourceIdentifer=bucket_name)

# Select the statement that will be modified
statement_to_modify = bucket_policy.select_statement('IPAllow')

# Insert new_user_arn into the list of Principal['AWS']
ip_address = ip_arr
statement_to_modify.Condition['IpAddress'].append(ip_address)

# Save change of the statement
statement_to_modify.save()

# Save change of the policy. This will update the bucket policy
statement_to_modify.source_policy.save() # Or bucket_policy.save()
```

When I run this command, I get this error:

statement_to_modify.Condition['IpAddress'].append(ip_address)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

I understand what it means but I dont know how to fix it. Please and Thank you for your assistance!!! I am open to public criticism....

Comment: From quick look at [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) `IpAddress` is an object/dict (not list), so maybe it will work like this: `statement_to_modify.Condition['IpAddress']['aws:SourceIp'] = ip_address.

As it's not a list, you can't provide multiple addresses, so my guess is you may need to add whole new condition.

Comment: It actually worked! thank you so much